# ¿Cómo iniciar aplicaciones de diversos tipos desde otra aplicación?

Tags: c#, .net

En [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) existen varios tipos de aplicaciones/modos de instalación. ¿Cómo se puede ejecutar desde una aplicación .Net otra atendiendo a estos criterios?

Comment: Esta pregunta pretende dar una respuesta canónica sobre como ejecutar una aplicación desde otra en C#. En todo caso, podría considerarse como _demasiado amplia_, mas que como _no está claro lo que se pregunta_ en mi opinión.

Comment: estoy de acuerdo, reabrámosla.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Iniciar aplicaciones conociendo su ruta

La principal manera de ejecutar una aplicación desde otra es usar  [`Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx). Por ejemplo,el siguiente código abre una instancia del Chrome:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe");
```

En este caso no necesita la ruta,ya que está en el path. Si no, se puede poner el path completo al ejecutable:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");
```

Si necesitas pasarle parámetros, puedes hacerlo también:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", "--incognito");
```

---

### Iniciar aplicaciones instaladas mediante Click Once

Para ejecutar aplicaciones ejecutadas mediante Click Once hay varias opciones:

- Si la aplicación fue instalada desde una URL (en una red local,por ejemplo), se puede ejecutar usando `Iexplore.exe` con la URL del archivo `.application` como parámetro:

  ```
  Process.Start("Iexplore.exe", "http://miServidor/aplicacion/aplicacion.application");
  ```

  Con esta opción, si la aplicación no está instalada, saltaría automáticamente el setup de la misma.
- Otra opción es buscar el archivo `appref-ms` que corresponde, sabiendo la carpeta del menu inicio donde se encuentra. Algo asi:

  ```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs));
  sb.Append("\\");
  sb.Append("CarpetaEnElMenuInicio");
  sb.Append("\\");
  sb.Append("MiAplicacion.appref-ms");
  string shortcutPath = sb.ToString();
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(shortcutPath);
  ```

---

### Iniciar aplicaciones UWP

Iniciar aplicaciones UWP es un poco más complejo. En [Automatizar el inicio de aplicaciones de Windows 10 para UWP](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/automate-launching-uwp-apps) se dan algunas opciones. Una es la siguiente:

- Obten el nombre de familia de paquete(Package Family Name) de la aplicación a ejecutar (puedes obtenerlo abriendo un PowerShell y ejecutando `get-appxpackage MiNombreDePaquete`)
- Ejecuta tu aplicación usando la app `appxlauncher.exe`:

  ```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\microsoft.windows.softwarelogo.appxlauncher.exe" MiNombreDePaquete_ph1m9x8skttmg!AppId
  ```

Hay otras opciones que puedes consultar en el enlace añadido anteriormente.